# Create autoincrement field with trigger and sequence in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

i'm triying to create an autoincrement field (like SERIAL) using a trigger and sequence. I know that only can use a sequence or SERIAL type on field, but i must resolve this using both methods (triggers and secuences)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AlimentosSequencia;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AlimentoFuncion()
  RETURNS "trigger" AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
      New.id:=nextval('AlimentosSequencia');
      Return NEW;
    END;
$BODY$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER AlimentosTrigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON alimento
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE AlimentoFuncion();
```

I try this combination but dosen't works, the table alimento has two fields only, integer id(the autoincrement with trigger and sequence) and the varchar name.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: just give some more explanation of "it doesn't work".

Comment: Why don't you want to use the simple SERIAL type?

Comment: You can just call `nextval()` on the associated sequence of a `serial` column for other purposes. No need to complicate things with a trigger. Aside from that, without error message, your question is just noise. Include it verbatim, please.

Comment: You could set the `nextval('AlimentosSequencia')` as the default value for this column, even when it is `integer`. No need of triggers.

Comment: it's an exercise guys, i must doit using trigger and sequence, here is not evaluating the performance. Thanks

Comment: Hi @jgiunta I have updated my answer and I don't understand, what's the error that give you your code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others users have told you, you don't need to use a trigger. You can declare the table like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AlimentosSequencia;

CREATE TABLE alimento (
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('AlimentosSequencia') PRIMARY KEY
 ,name VARCHAR(255));
```

And when you insert a new record:

```
INSERT INTO alimento (name) VALUES ('lemon');
```

Another possibility is declared the **id** field as [*serial type*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL), that it would create the sequence automatically.

**UPDATE:**
Ok, it's an exercise. Then I don't understand what's the problem? I have tested this code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AlimentosSequencia;

CREATE TABLE alimento (
  id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 ,name VARCHAR(255));

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AlimentoFuncion()
 RETURNS "trigger" AS
 $BODY$
 BEGIN
   New.id:=nextval('AlimentosSequencia');
   Return NEW;
 END;
 $BODY$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

 CREATE TRIGGER AlimentosTrigger
 BEFORE INSERT
 ON alimento
 FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE AlimentoFuncion();

 INSERT INTO alimento (name) VALUES ('lemon');
```

And it works without problems.

Comment: The problem was when i declared de ID field ... :( !!!! But readng your answer i detect the problem. Thanks again